# Sliding Divs --> Multi

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

i used this script to animate some divs with jquery and css. now i would like to use more than these two buttons. instead there should be several lists underneath. but i cannot just copy each jquery script and change the name of the vars.

here is the example: http://jonathanstark.com/labs/simple-sliding-example-using-css3-animations.html

how can i change the vars and the script, so the script would be for every combination of any "settings" + "home" div? Like a vertical menu and on each "home" div the combined "settings" div slides in.

```
<script>
            function goTo(targetPanelId) {
                var home = document.getElementById('home');
                var settings = document.getElementById('settings');
                if (targetPanelId === 'settings') {
                    home.className = 'slide left out';
                    settings.className = 'slide left in';                    
                } else {
                    home.className = 'slide right in';
                    settings.className = 'slide right out';                    
                }
                return false;
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: `slide left in` are 3 classes? The demo does not work in FF.

Comment: its for webkit browser. its for an iPhone mobile site. and slide left in is only one class.

Comment: I do believe that classnames can't have spaces in - try hyphenating things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my code, hope this is what you wanted:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SyL7n/20/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="home">
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <a href="#" class="menu" data-hash="settings-1"><span>Go to Settings 1</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu" data-hash="settings-2"><span>Go to Settings 2</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu" data-hash="settings-3"><span>Go to Settings 3</span></a>
        <p>Animation Example</p>
        <p>When a button is clicked/tapped, the JavaScript merely assigns class names to the panels. The CSS then jumps into action based on the new class names.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="settings">
        <h1>Settings</h1>
        <a id="settings-1" href="#" class="menu" data-hash="home"><span>Go to Home 1</span></a>
        <a id="settings-2" href="#" class="menu" data-hash="home"><span>Go to Home 2</span></a>
        <a id="settings-3" href="#" class="menu" data-hash="home"><span>Go to Home 3</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function goTo(link) {
    var hash = link.dataset['hash'],
        target = document.getElementById(hash),
        source = link.parentNode,
        isHome = source.id == 'home';

    if(isHome) {
        target.className = 'slide left in';
    }else{
        link.className = 'slide right out';
    }

    return false;
}

var navs = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
for(var i in navs) {
    var obj = navs[i];
    if(typeof obj == 'object') {
        obj.addEventListener('click', function() {
            goTo(this);
        });
    }
}
```

Note the removed p tags, I had to make the anchor the whole width of its parent with a span for the button style, because else 100% x-translation would not be the complete animation.